# Testing code that uses process.on('unhandledRejection') with AVA

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, ava

How do I use AVA to test a library that registers an `unhandledRejection` callback:

```
  process.on('unhandledRejection', e =>
    // do something effectful
  );
```

In this environment, unhandled rejections are not necessarily errors in the library.  I want to ensure that my library is robust against users' callbacks causing an unhandled rejection.

Without a way to do this, I have to use a different testing framework (like Tape) to execute those tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVA will consider unhandled rejections in test files to be a failure. You'd have to run your code "elsewhere", being a child process or worker thread.

---

> I want to ensure that my library is robust against users' callbacks causing an unhandled rejection.

IMHO that's your users problem. If your library calls user provided code and you're awaiting a promise return value you *could* try / catch that error, but arguably letting the program crash is perfectly valid.